# Form is submitting empty values though it's required in the datasource (Google App Maker)

Tags: google-app-maker

Could someone please help me how to display error message when I am submitting form and validating whether all the required fields are filled with data or not in Google App Maker, I have tried by using regular expressions but it didn't work:

[image: Image of form]

Comment: Show your code please ?

Comment: Hi, I have attached image now my form has few fields like employee name, email I have marked as required in Datasource of this page in the field of employee name when I am submitting form I need to display error message if the any of the fields are empty, I have used regular expression for not keeping the employee field as empty but it is not reflecting when I am submitting form